# GestureRecognizer is not working when i click on URL in text

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uitextview

I have two methods running synchronously a gesturetap recogniser and a shouldInteractWithURL in a UITextView.

gesturetap recognizer gives me the x,y cordinates of tapped point when tapped anywhere except URL's at which point shouldInteractWithURL is called. How do i get the CGPoint of the URL tapped.

Here are both my methods.

```
// Tap GestureRecognizer function
- (void)tapGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint tappedPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat xCoordinate = tappedPoint.x;
    CGFloat yCoordinate = tappedPoint.y;

    NSLog(@"Touch Using UITapGestureRecognizer x : %f y : %f", xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
}

//URL Interaction
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange {

//here goes my logic
    NSLog(@"Touch Using UITapGestureRecognizer x : %f y : %f", xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
}

//gesture load in ViewDidLoad
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureRecognizer:)];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

When clicked the URL ideally i would think, tapgesture would be executed first and then the url interaction. but it doesn't happen so.

Comment: can u show ur gesture allocation method

Comment: edit added. pls check.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you added the tapGestureRecognizer in your view and not on your UITextView, try this.:

`[self.yourUITextView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need the location of the text view you can do the following:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange {

CGFloat xCoordinate = textView.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat yCoordinate = textView.frame.origin.y;

// OR the following

CGFloat xCoordinate = textView.center.x;
CGFloat yCoordinate = textView.center.y;

//your logic next
NSLog(@"Touch Using UITapGestureRecognizer x : %f y : %f", xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
}
```

otherwise you will need to add your gesture recogniser to the textView itself but the coordinates will be shown in the textView coordinates system, not the entire current self.view. You will have to calculate the exact point location for example like this:

```
CGPoint tappedPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
CGFloat xCoordinate = textView.center.x+tappedPoint.x;
CGFloat yCoordinate = textView.center.y+tappedPoint.y;
```